# Is there any way how to disable battery in laptop or stop charging on dell?

Tags: battery

I need to find some way how to stop charging a laptop or disable the battery. So when I unplug my laptop it will instantly shut down. But I can't find anything related to this. I have dell G3 17inch.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible, and there is no software out there that does this. The latest post and update from [Dell Support](https://www.dell.com/community/Vostro/how-to-disable-battery-charging-while-it-is-plugged-in/td-p/6188754) has some details. The only way to prevent charging is to remove the battery in its entirety.

I have a small suggestion, Dell Power Manager is able to manipulate the battery (plugged in), you can set the battery to stop charging at certain percentage threshold (stop charging at 55%), with reference from the [Dell Power Manager User Guide](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/power-manager_users-guide_en-us.pdf) you can't set a percentage lower than 55%. If you want to minimize battery use, you can look into that option.

Dell Power Manager also has another option called,

> "**Primarily AC**" - Extends battery life by lowering the charge threshold, so that the battery never charges to 100 percent capacity.
>   Recommended for users who primarily operate the system while plugged into an external power source.

Comment: I am not actually looking for a way how to extend battery life just needed to turn it off when not plugged. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Dell Power Manager's default setting is `Adaptive` which should be equal to `Primarily AC`  if you really do primarly use AC. i.e. there should be no need to touch this setting, unless for some reason you want it on even when you use your battery instead of AC.